# i can not add any dependency on flutter like google font, and lottie

Tags: flutter, fonts, lottie

Because day13 depends on google_fonts >=2.3.1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.10.0-0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because day13 depends on google_fonts >=2.3.1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.10.0-0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

Comment: in the pubspec.yaml file, instead of providing the package version, type in `any`. For example: `google_fonts: any`. Does that help?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to update the flutter SDK version of your project to >=2.10.0-0 if that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the version of you google_fonts package in your pubspec.yaml.

Try to change it to a 2.3.0 or below. Check versions here that will work:

https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts/versions